# Can time-till-rest be used as a hub-regrease-and-repack flag?

Tags: hub, preventative-maintenance, grease

The traditional way to determine whether the hubs need repacking, regreasing, and perhaps a ball bearing change is to grab the two sides of the fork or both seatstays after spinning the corresponding wheel. If any vibration or grinding can be felt, it's time to open the hub to inspect and correct.

But suppose I don't want to wait until grinding can be felt. Suppose that after 1-2 years of using a new bike, I have the impression, but can't prove, that the rear wheel used to spin for far longer until rest than it does now.

Can I use the following? When I get a new bike, I spin the rear wheel as fast as I can, and count the seconds until it stops on its own. At every tune-up thereafter, I do the same. If the time is shorter by, say, 25%, it's time for a regrease/repack.

The idea being that if I wait until grinding can be felt, I would have waited not only until the grease is gone, but by then the ball bearings, the cones, or the hubs might have already been damaged. If on the other hand I clean and repack the grease before grinding can be felt, then it's simply a question of adding fresh grease, with no need to replace any parts.

Comment: Spinning the axle alone (wheel removed from frame) with your fingers is a much better way of detecting problems than spinning the entire wheel. A little preventative maintenance isn’t a bad idea either.

Comment: @MaplePanda Re: "_A little preventative maintenance isn’t a bad idea either._" No question there. I'm sure we all enjoy giving a bit of loving and pamper our bike(s) long before they ask for it, but grease cleaning and repacking in particular is rather of the messy variety.

Comment: @MaplePanda Re: "_Spinning the axle alone (wheel removed from frame) with your fingers is a much better way of detecting problems than spinning the entire wheel._" This I don't understand. Why is spinning just the axle better? It may very well be true. I just have no sense for why it would be true. Doesn't spinning the entire wheel amplify any micro-irregularities, whereas spinning just the axle might keep the vibrations microscopic, below our ability to sense them? Even if it's so bad that there is already play between axle and hub, wouldn't moving the entire wheel show more wiggling motion?

Comment: Yeah it’s one of the messier jobs around, but nothing a pair of gloves and a stack of paper towel can’t fix. Regarding the axle, your assumption is backwards. The angular momentum of the wheel masks any bearing issues (unless they’re so bad that the wheel stops in 5 seconds or something, in which case I reckon you should start looking for a new hub). Also, you have a lever effect if you spin the whole wheel that again masks issues. Try spinning just the axle sometime; the difference is immediate and obvious. Yes, wiggling the wheel is the best way to check for play.

Comment: Isn't grinding a sign that the bearings and their cages _already are_ significantly damaged?

Comment: @Vikki Yes, that's the premise/concern of the question.

Comment: @Sam: OK.  (The current wording seems to say that grinding is a warning of _future_ damage, rather than indicating that significant damage _has already occurred._)

Comment: @Vikki Happy to edit to make the wording more precise. But I wrote "_when grinding can be felt, the grease is gone **and** the ball bearings, the cones, or the hubs might be damaged_". Could you point to the segment that suggested that grinding is a warning of _future_ damage?

Comment: @Sam: The "be" in "might be damaged" could easily be read as meaning "become" - "and the ball bearings, the cones, or the hubs might become damaged" - in which case it implies that damage might occur _if you continue to operate the bike_.  I initially read it that way, for example, and only later realized that you were saying "and the ball bearings, the cones, or the hubs might [already] be damaged".

Comment: I've gotten a couple different brand new wheel sets that had a very sparse amount of grease coating the bearings.  Point is the first hub overhaul should come sooner rather than later.  I prefer to repack my hubs and replace the loose ball bearings twice a year since I ride all year in all conditions. It's relatively inexpensive and extend the life of a hub exponentially.  Cartridge bearing hubs get the seals removed, the insides flushed and brushed and repacked with clean grease, then pay particular attention to returning the undamaged seals fully set in their seat.

Comment: @Jeff Point taken, but that makes no sense. Grease is far from being an expensive iitem, and new wheels come, one assumes, with a warranty. The manufacturer is liable during the first phase of use. Why would they not add a proper type & amount of grease to minimize the percentage of wheels returning with warranty claims?

Comment: @Vikki Understood. Okay, fixed. Please review.

Comment: @Sam: Looks much clearer now. :-)

Comment: @Sam I cannot say why there was such a minimal amount of grease in the new wheel sets I've purchased. You make a good point about their warranty liability.  Saving a few pennies on grease risking dollars for replacement wheels.  In the last few years I've purchased 3 MTB wheel sets from 3 different places. Only the second purchase was from the company that actually built the wheel. I ordered the hubs, rims, spokes a'la'cart and they built it up. Hubs were all Shimano: XT and Deore. All with very minimal amounts of grease. I'm talking scant. Only opened the first to replace the axle with an XTR

Comment: @Jeff I agree with your findings. The brand-new XTR hub I bought had a fairly ...competitive... quantity of grease in it (perhaps to be expected for XTR?) The drag caused by grease may be a factor as many people think grease and seal drag = bad bearing quality.

Comment: @Jeff Good point. Might it be that factories are preparing bikes for racers, as well as for the customers who will measure the quality of the wheels by some random metric, and the rest of us are best advised to repack soon after buying, especially if the wheels are particularly meant for  performance? Let's ask https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/82183/48599

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keeping tabs on the condition of the hub as you describe could provide some interesting data that does relate to how in need of maintenance it is, but it also has these issues if you were trying to use it as the only indicator:

- Spinning it as fast as you can makes it hard to spin it with the same amount of force each time, which is needed in order for your observations to mean anything. Better to disengage the chain (to get freehub resistance out of the reading), rotate the wheel so that the valve and seam are on the horizontal, let it pendulum, and then count swings.
- Seal drag could have an outsized influence on any test of this sort. For example, take any random hub that has contact seals (as most do somewhere), do your test, then add a drop of lube to the seal and you'll probably get a very different result. Contact seals can be perfectly far away from the main bearing and how they're fairing doesn't necessarily have anything to do with whether the hub bearings need overhaul.
- There's not perfect overlap between conditions where hub bearings spin rougher unweighted and conditions where contamination or lubricant failure threaten to damage them. If you put together a hub with just oil and spin it in the stand, it will go vastly longer than with grease.

It's very important with bearings to understand that when we spin a wheel in the stand or in hand, or spin the axle manually, we are *not* getting a read that's necessarily reflective of how the bearing would feel under the load and flex of a real rider. We get some information doing those things, but not perfect information. Most of the information we get relates to the presence or absence of contamination, the quality of the preload adjustment, the condition of the bearing surfaces, and an approximation of how the lubrication is doing.

What hurts hubs is contamination in the bearing or breakdown of the grease from wear or water ingress. If if weren't for those things, good quality cup and cone hubs could last an extremely long time with no maintenance. In the real world, you need to overhaul when those conditions begin to develop, which is probably going to be a subjective determination. It would be nice if there were a way of quantifying when exactly it warrants it (i.e. X grit ppm is acceptable but Y is too much), but for practical purposes there isn't. A reasonable approach is do a first overhaul at a nice and conservative interval from new (say 2000 miles in), then take note of the conditions inside and the time of year it was ridden, and then go from there in playing it longer or shorter next time. On good quality hubs (very hard races with good machining and finish) it's also wise to interpret play developing in the bearings as a sign to at least check the internal conditions and possibly overhaul, since the material loss that caused the looseness could easily have been caused by contamination or depletion of the grease (and on good hubs that are past initial break-in, developing play is more often a sign that the ideal maintenance interval has been exceeded.)

Answer (score 8):

The problem with unloaded (no outside weight/force applied) spin tests is that grease is viscous. An unloaded bearing without grease can actually spin more easily than a properly packed one. It’s only under load that grease will improve performance and the losses due to its viscosity can be neglected¹.

So take out the wheel, spin the axle by hand. Check if it turns smoothly. You can even develop a feel for greasy-ness.

With some hubs the quick release skewer applies enough force to slightly compress the axle and bearings. With such hubs you’ll have to adjust for some bearing play outside of the bike which should go away after you’ve installed the wheel and tightened the quick release skewer.

One more thing on spin tests: How long something (crankset, wheel etc.) spins without load depends not only on grease/bearing losses but also on rotational inertia. A heavy wheel (especially if it has heavy tyres) will rotate much longer than a light one.

¹: Some very performance oriented people use less viscous grease or even oil to reduce those tiny losses, especially in colder conditions.